# Button ImageSize x-dimension ignored

Tags: graphics, interface

How can a small square button be created with `ImageSize -> {20,20}`?

The x-dimension won't go below about 70.

(Using version 9.0.1 on OS X.)

```
Grid[{
  {Button["", ImageSize -> {10, 10}],
   Button["", ImageSize -> {20, 20}]},
  {Button["", ImageSize -> {30, 30}],
   Button["", ImageSize -> {90, 30}]}},
 Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me W7 MMA 8.0.

Comment: Win 7 V9.0 looks also Ok.

Comment: Thanks. I recall this working ok on Windows.

Comment: Works fine on Linux 8.0 too.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that on OS X the default appearance "style  button" has a minimum size. Note below that `Appearance` has to be set locally within each button rather than in the `Style` wrapper.

```
Style[
 Grid[{{
    Button["x", Null, Appearance -> None, ImageSize -> {10, 10}],
    Button["x", Null, Appearance -> None, ImageSize -> {20, 20}]},
   {Button["x", Null, Appearance -> None, ImageSize -> {30, 30}],
    Button["x", Null, Appearance -> None, ImageSize -> {90, 30}]}},
  Frame -> All,
  ItemSize -> All,
  Alignment -> Left],
 DefaultOptions -> {
   Button -> {
     Background -> Orange,
     BaseStyle -> Directive[FontColor -> Black, 11]
     }
   }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. `Appearance -> "Palette"` is a palatable solution.